# Capture video stream in python

Tags: python, node.js, stream, video-streaming

I would like to be able to capture a video stream in Python from a internet address.

For my example I am streaming from VLC to this node.js app via http:
https://github.com/sinclairzx81/vlc.web.stream

And then this node app exposes this live stream to localhost:5000/stream. Now I would like to capture this stream and show it realtime using opencv for instance.